# Help understanding the definition of a specific measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

In an exercise, I am supposed to determine if a measure is finite or $\sigma$-finite, however, I do not understand the definition of said measure. The measure is defined as a "Borel measure on $[1,\infty)$ given by the density function, $1/x$, with respect to the 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure". Now, I know the definition of the Lebesgue measure, but what exactly is meant by a measure "given by the density function with respect to the Lebesgue measure"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the measure $\mu$ is defined by
$$
\mu(A) = \int_A\frac{d\lambda(x)}{x}
$$
for any Borel $A\subseteq [1,\infty)$, with the integral being a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: One question: I assume you mean $d\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Hydrogen Yes. I'll fix that.